# Когда надо использовать универсальные ссылки?

Tags: c++, ссылки

В каких случаях стоит использовать универсальные ссылки, кроме как с std::forward? Почему нельзя просто использовать const T&?

Comment: Никто не знает?

Comment: Непонятна логика про forward. По идее делают наоборот - сначала решают, что нужна универсальная ссылка, а потом расставляют `forward` где нужно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat когда надо использовать кроме случаев када мы форвардим?

Comment: Почти никогда, поэтому стандарт и некоторые авторы называют их forwarding references, а не "универсальные". В чем разница с rvalue-ссылками понятно?

Comment: Это же и есть рвэлью ссылки но для шаблонного параметра

Comment: То есть кроме када форвардим никогда не используется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В голову приходит один пример. Допустим, вы пишете что-то типа `std::for_each` (функция зашаблонена типом лямбды, которую нужно вызвать больше одного раза; и/или зашаблонена типами аргументов).

`std::forward` легально вызывать только на последнем вызове лямбды, а добавлять проверку, последний это вызов или нет, не хочется (либо сложно, либо выглядит неэффективно). Поэтому можно лямбду принимать как `typename T` `T &&func`, а вызывать вообще без `std::forward`.

Почему не передавать `const T &func`? Потому что `operator()` может быть неконстантный.

Внимательный читатель возразит, что `std::for_each` принимает лямбду по значению - но они делают это зря (вот кому может понадобиться специально копировать лямбду с захватом??), в своих функциях я бы использовал forwarding ссылку.

---

Еще можно схитрить и вспомнить про [`std::forward_like`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward_like), который иногда нужен вместо `std::forward`.